# Fatal Exception at AnroidRuntime after releasing new update

Tags: android, obfuscation, android-proguard, runtimeexception

After updating for a new release of my app I'm getting this error crash repeatedly on the opening of the app and nothing else. This crash happening after few seconds of the opening of the app.

Error Log:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-3
Process: com.company.app, PID: 13304
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No direct method <init>(Lorg/apache/http/c/c;Lorg/apache/http/conn/scheme/SchemeRegistry;)V in class Lorg/apache/http/impl/conn/tsccm/ThreadSafeClientConnManager; or its super classes (declaration of 'org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager' appears in /system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar)
    at com.a.g.c.c(Unknown Source:54)
    at com.a.g.c.a(Unknown Source:4)
    at com.a.e.b.a(Unknown Source:0)
    at com.a.e.b.b(Unknown Source:23000)
    at com.a.d.b.c(Unknown Source:5000)
    at com.a.d.b.b(Unknown Source:0)
    at com.a.d.b.a(Unknown Source:4000)
    at com.a.c.f.a(Unknown Source:12000)
    at com.a.c.f$1.run(Unknown Source:4)
    at com.a.a.b.b.a(Unknown Source:8)
    at com.a.e.a(Unknown Source:51031)
    at com.a.e.a(Unknown Source:0)
    at com.a.e$4.run(Unknown Source:1000)
    at com.a.e.o(Unknown Source:31)
    at com.a.e.a(Unknown Source:45000)
    at com.a.c.a(Unknown Source:20)
    at com.a.c.b(Unknown Source:27000)
    at com.a.c$1.run(Unknown Source:7)
    at com.a.a.b.c.run(Unknown Source:8)
    at com.a.a.b.d.run(Unknown Source:2000)
```

This error is showing in Logcat not getting on Crashlytics.
What are the main causes of this happening and how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What are the main causes of this happening and how to solve this problem?

This is due to your apache classes are stripped by your proguard obfuscation step. Try to add `-keep` options for those apache classes. E.g.

```
-keep class org.apache.http.** { *; }
```

Comment: But this release working in some of many devices and in many crashes frequently

Comment: you can double check if the required class exists in your apk using **apkanalyser**.